# os.path.exists return false for some of the paths

Tags: python, windows, path

Can someone explain to me how the following result is possible for this piece of code in Python:

```
for f in glob.glob(<dir-path>+"\\*"):
       print(os.path.exists(f))
```

and the result:

```
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
True
```

The directories I work on are network folders but the issue hasn't happened before on other directories there. I checked and there is no difference in the permissions between the files in the directory.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The first debugging step would be to do `print(os.path.exists(f), f)` to find out which paths are causing the issue.

Comment: first you should display `f` to see what path makes problem - and you should check directly in system if this path exists. Maybe it was temporary file and it existed when `glob()` was running but it was deleted (by system) when `exists()` was running.

Comment: The paths that are making the problem are normal ones and doesn't lead to temporary files. Any other debugging suggestion?

Comment: What if you use  `print(os.path.exists(f), os.path.exists('\\\\?\\'+f), f)`?